# Problem running task manager with import pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-task-scheduler

I want to schedule some python code to be executed every week using task scheduler. I have some python scripts that I am able to successfully automate with task scheduler. However, when i import pandas into the script, task manager fails to execute. I tested with some code. First I simply write two txt files and task scheduler was able to do this. However when I imported pandas in between the two writes only the first write was executed by task manager. If import pandas is above both writes then neither will execute. Anyone know why import pandas would clash with task manager and how to fix?

```
f=open('test3.txt','w')
f.write("hello world")
f.close() 

f=open('test1.txt','w')
f.write("hello world")
f.close()
```

```
f=open('test3.txt','w')
f.write("hello world")
f.close() 

import pandas

f=open('test1.txt','w')
f.write("hello world")
f.close()
```

```
import pandas

f=open('test3.txt','w')
f.write("hello world")
f.close() 

f=open('test1.txt','w')
f.write("hello world")
f.close()
```

Task scheduler will execute the first block of code.

Task scheduler will only execute first write of 'test3.txt'.

Task scheduler will not execute any of the code.

Anyone have any knowledge about this/any solutions?

Comment: If you double click on each individual script, are you able to run them manually?

Comment: There is a possibility, that pandas is not installed or installed properly.

Comment: yes they will run if i run them manually. Is it possible that pandas is not installed properly if i have a script loaded with pandas commands that work when I run manually?

Comment: In that case, how is your settings in task scheduler? Did you create a bat. file first to run python script or you set them directly to your python script?

Comment: I did not create a bat file.It is set directly to python script.

Comment: Try to create a bat file. Set it to run bat file instead of py file. Step 3 on this website shall guide you [Create Your Bat File](https://datatofish.com/python-script-windows-scheduler/)

Comment: So i was using anaconda package to work with python and this installation already has pandas installed. However, i never installed pandas in my command window which was causing the issue. When I would try to run the bat file it would say pandas not installed. I installed pandas through command line (pip install pandas) and it works now. Thanks for you help!

Comment: Wow, glad everything works now! You're welcome.